# Map disappearing when adding graphic layers using Web ADF of ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, wms, arcgis-web-adf

I'm trying to add a graphic layer in a web ADF application with arcGIS for asp.net, but every time I add a graphic layer to the MapResourceManager, the map disappears!

To better understand this: here's the simple app with the only element in the MapResourceManager being the map service (OGC (WMS) Service) which provides me the map

http://imageshack.us/f/715/pro2w.jpg/

And here's the MapResourceManager with another graphic layer, the map misteriously disappears

http://imageshack.us/f/543/pro1y.jpg/

What's wrong with that?

Comment: What are the displaysettings of your graphic layer?  Is transparent true?

Comment: It was visible, the problem was a javascript issue I'm posting down here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out, warning: javascript at line indicated by javascript debuggers like firebug or chrome's integrated one is bugged, combobox name is case-sensitive and you need to correct it

Answer (score 2):

I have not had much experience with the ArcGIS Web offering, but I've experienced something similar in ArcMap.

The first thing I can suggest is check that the spatial reference (AKA projection) is the same for both files.  A difference in these can sometimes cause applications to inaccurately project the data to your screen.

Though recently, I have had a data set where the coordinates were scaled up by 100. i.e, the x coordinate should have been 160,000 and the y = 80,000,000, but x = 16,000,000 and y = 8,000,000,000.

So it may be worth your while to check the bounding box of the data set and make sure the coordinates fit within the boundaries of the its defined Spatial Reference.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep this in mind for future problems, anyway I've solved with some javascript debugging. I'm posting here what I did to help other people